# What is this component below the fuselage of the Fokker F28 used for?

Tags: feature-identification, fokker-f28

There is a long straight component with three attachment points below the fuselage of the Fokker F28 Fellowship:

[image: F28]
<sup>(image modified from [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Piedmont_F-28-1000.jpg))</sup>

It looks like it is installed on both sides of the fuselage:

[image: F28]
<sup>(image modified from [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Scandinavian_Airlines_F-28-4000.jpg))</sup>

**What is this component used for?**

Comment: Possibly an ADF sense antenna?

Answer (score 1):

those are antenna supports, probably for a radio navigation system, that hold the thin antenna rod in a straight line and keep it from vibrating in flight.